# PHP preg_replace() with a pair of curly brackets, but ignore the ones with 3

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Wanted to know if this is possible

```
$c = "The color {{ white }} will become {{ white }}.";

$c = preg_replace("#{{\s*white\s*}}#", "black", $c);
```

the result will be

```
The color black will become black.
```

Is there a way to ignore it if it's enclosed with additional { and } or any other character so this

```
$c = "The color {{{ white }}} will become {{ white }}.";
```

will become instead

```
The color {{ white }} will become black.
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$c = preg_replace("#{{(?!{)\s*white\s*}}(?!})#", "black", $c);
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/76311)

Comment: Thanks, but it displays as {{{ white }}}, is there a way to negate AND remove the additional curly brackets, so it will become instead {{ white }} within this regex in one go? Thank you!

Comment: @user702300: I think you'll have to do it in two steps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex `/\{{2,3}\s*white\s*\}{2,3}/`. Here it is in your example.

```
$c = "The color {{{ white }}} will become {{ white }}.";

echo preg_replace("/\{{2,3}\s*white\s*\}{2,3}/", "black", $c);
```

The `\{` and `\}` indicates a bracket. And the `{2,3}` indicates it’s either 2 or 3 brackets it should match.